# Command to show storage usage on HP MSA 2040 SAN?

Tags: storage-area-network, hp-modular-smart-array

Is there any way to show me the usage on HP MSA2040 SAN storage?

I am searching this for while, but no luck at all. I need to know the usage of the entire SAN storage by just running command from cli or script, I dont see any cli command gives me the information I am looking for.

Each time I have to login to web console to find out the status of the SAN. Is there a script or command can do this?

Comment: Play with 'show volume-statistics', well so long as you're not using linear mode anyway.

Comment: `show volume-statistics` gives no usage information